# Trying to add an attribute called "key" to a custom element but React is removing it

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, custom-element

I'm building a static site in React (using the Gatsby framework).

The site is for a yoga studio and I need to embed a studio booking form widget onto a page. The widget is provided by a service called GymCatch. To embed their widget you must add a custom html element with an attribute called "key" - into which you paste your api key:

```
<gymcatch-embedded key="xxx-xxx-xxx"></gymcatch-embedded>
```

There is then an external javascript file that runs to replace this element with the embedded form.

The `key` attribute is obviously used extensively in React and is a reserved attribute name. It therefore doesn't make it to the DOM.

Can anyone think of a way that I can add this attribute to my element but not have it removed by React?

Comment: Have you tried to place the tag in the HTML file?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to inject arbitrary HTML into the DOM.  Obviously if this involved any user input you'd need to sanitize it first, but for this sort of thing it's safe:

```js
const Foo = () => {
  const customtag = {
    __html: '<gymcatch-embedded key="xxx-xxx-xxx"></gymcatch-embedded>'
  };  
  
  return (
    <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={customtag} />
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  (<Foo/>), document.getElementById("root")
);

// proof:
console.log(document.getElementById("root").innerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Change the letter case of `key` to work it out. `Key`, `kEy`, `keY`, `KEY`, either is okay.**

This is because JavaScript and JSX is case-sensitive while HTML attribute is not. React has occupied `key` but other spellings in different letter cases haven't.